# VisualComposer/WPBakery Page Editor: Is any JS event triggered after the Edition pop-in is shown?

Tags: javascript, visual-editor

In the back-office, when we create a page, we can add sections and rows in which we can create elements. These elements are for example text boxes, images,  buttons, and other Visual Composer mappings manually declared in `functions.php` for example, using the function `vc_map`.

When we want to add one of these elements to a section/row, we click on its icon and another pop-in is shown. The latter contains fields required by the element (the text and the image for a button, etc.).

This question is about *this* pop-in. Is there any JavaScript event triggered after it's opened? Is it possible to listen for it?

I saw that an AJAX query is sent asking for `admin-ajax.php` and then `edit-form.min.js`.

I can look for PHP hooks and filters too, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: add an action on the tag `vc_edit_form_fields_after_render`.

```
    add_action( 'vc_edit_form_fields_after_render', function() {
        echo  '<script src="' . AN_URL . 'test.js"></script>';  // Or something other
    }, 9 );
```

*In the `functions.php` or equivalent.*

(Indeed, the tag `vc_edit_form_fields_after_render` is used by `do_action( 'vc_edit_form_fields_after_render' )` which is located in `js_composer\include\classes\editors\class-vc-edit-form-fields.php` . So what you type in your `add_action` callable will be executed after, and only after, the user has opened the Edition pop-in presented in the OP message - this is what I was asking for).